# Looping over uploaded files to present a clean HTML form for each one

Tags: javascript, html, json, forms, frontend

I'm building a website that asks users to upload a selection of images.  Once some sanity and safety checks have been completed on those images, I'd like to present some forms so that the users can give us context for the given image.  The information for each form will then be placed into a JSON file that is associated with each image before these are all uploaded to a server.

My **question** is how can I loop through the images, presenting a clean form for each one?

The other parts of the problem (like labelling the form with the name of the current image) should be a trivial extension of the above, and there are plenty of tutorials on how to take HTML form data and whack it into a JSON, or at least a JavaScript object that I can then stringify, but if you could provide at least a minimal working example that would be great.  I've provided below a skeleton of the code with the most of the domain specific details missing

HTML code

```
<form>
  <h3 id="image_name"></h3>
  <label for="lighting">Lighting condition</label>
        <br>
        <input list="lighting" name="lighting">
        <datalist id="lighting">
          <option value="Dimly lit from the front"></option>
          <option value="Dimly lit from behind"></option>
          <option value="Brightly lit from the front"></option>
          <option value="Brightly lit from behind"></option>
        </datalist><br><br>
  </form>
```

Some of the JS code

```
var img_iterator = formData.values();
function set_image_title(){
    var cur_image_name = document.getElementById("image_name");
    var cur_image = img_iterator.next().value;
    cur_image_name.innerHTML = cur_image.name;
}
```